# How to push data from java servlet to android client

Tags: android, servlets, push

I am working with a servlet app (server) and an android app (client) and i need to push some data from server app to android client. I do not have the android phone number, maybe i could get the ip of android phone.
how can i do this task? Thanks

Comment: You may integrate FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) both on server & client.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). It is the only way to push messages from server to android client

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do i need to have client phone number to push data in using FCM?

Comment: No. You need to add some code to your client https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client